# How to get uploaded video metadata by javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, video

I can't find a way to read video's metadata (like title,authour,ecc...) of a video, by javascript. I have a form with an input type file and with:

```
var selectedFile = $(".select-file").prop("files")[0];
console.log(selectedFile);
```

i obtain only those keys:

```
lastModified:1504258094000
lastModifiedDate:Fri Sep 01 2017 11:28:14 GMT+0200 (CEST)
name:"filename.mp4"
size:875978
type:"video/mp4"
```

Where are the others keys? Maybe i have to use a FileReader ?

Comment: check out the mp4js library - https://github.com/lennart/mp4/blob/master/dist/mp4.js

Comment: Share a testable link to a small (file size) example of MP4 with your expected metadata. Yes, for JS you must use FileReader.